# node-rdkafka erorr while installing

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, node-kafka

I'm using Wind 10, from long time a tried to install node-rdkafka, but it didn't work,I tried to find a solution  for it but failed, so i used another client(node-kafka) but it not strong like nod-rdkafka,

I tried all the possible solutions but still not be able to installed

already installed visual studio latest community version with c++ desktop build tools,

I'm using node@v16.15.1, npm@8.11.0, node-gyp@9.1.0, Python 3.10.7

the full error logs if any one can help me.[ERROR_LOG](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1enTasTrMBBO4_dBDqtYvWkamMR9ZK__5)

Answer (score 0):

unable to install **node-rdkafka** with "npm install"
Same error occurred for me with node version 16.4.2 , node-gyp@9.1.0 and python@3.10.7

[image]